# Using Devise gem, how do i display username with comment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, comments

New to devise. I am using a partial form to post a comment.  I was wondering how may I pass the current user into the form. so that i can use it to display what user posted what comment.  I tried doing something like :current_user => current_user.name but get a undefined local variable because there is no instance of the user in scope. Any suggestions?

```
<%= form_for Comment.new(:party_id => party.id), :remote => :true do |f| %>
            <div class="field">
                <%= f.hidden_field :party_id %>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <%= f.text_area :body %>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <%= f.submit %>
            </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devise is providing [view helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers). So this should be enough

```
<%= current_user.name %>
```

Comment: <div class="comments-part">
    <%= current_user.name %>
    <%= comment.body %>
</div>        I've added it to my comments partial yet the name still isn't yielding. Do i need to declare it in my comments-form partial as well??

Comment: Thank you that worked, i noticed i didn't submit a name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you add this as a hidden field, will users still be able to change the value that they send with the form if they inspect the html code. You should instead do this in the controller action. I also think it would be better with a association instead of just a name.

```
# in Comment model
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...

# in User model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  ...

# in CommentsController 
def create
  @comment = current_user.comments.build(params[:comment]) # current_user is a devise helper method
  if @comment.save
    ...
```